# Three Div Containers Side-by-side: 33.3333333% not working?

Tags: css, html, containers

I have a div container with a width 1000px, and within it three divs width 33.333333%, all float:left.

There's maybe one or two pixels' width that isn't covered by this 99.999999% where the 100%-width container div shows through (see picture- red pixels on right side).

How can I fix this, preferably without making it four divs for an even 25% each?

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You Can Get an Exact and Flexible Solution

If you only `float` and set the `width` on the first two elements, and then set either `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` (just not `visible`) on the third element, then [the magic works](http://web.archive.org/web/20150618153020/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/?) to automatically fill the remaining space, so that there will *never* be a gap.

[See this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sVu4R/9/), where I've overridden the values for the `:last-child` div to make this happen.

Comment: If I give #king3 only width:200px;, it actually works, too!  Is Overflow: Hidden/Auto  really necessary?

Comment: @user2824289: Yes, the `overflow` value is what causes the browser to change how it renders the un-floated element. Did you go to [the page I linked to that explains it](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)?

Comment: Gotcha...honestly, I didn't, I am now, though.  I just didn't notice a difference with overflow:hidden added, but as you said, I would with resizing and rendering.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.container {
            width: 1000px;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #5cabc1;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        div.box {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
            width: 33.3%;
            float: left;
        }

        div.b1 {
            background: #fca502;
        }

        div.b2 {
            background: #ffff00;
        }

        div.b3 {
            background: #afcfe4;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box b1">div 1</div>
        <div class="box b2">div 3</div>
        <div class="box b3">div 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVu4R/5/

Comment: If you make the box 1000px wide, you see that it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/sVu4R/2/

Comment: I tested it both in Firefox and IE, and it doesn't work. See the fiddle that I linked to.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I've updated the link and code, all divs line up properly for me.

Comment: The elements don't fill up the container.

Comment: @Guffa View http://jsfiddle.net/sVu4R/5/ with 1000px without issues. You're correct, your jsfiddle shows an extra pixel.

Comment: @Guffa `width: 33.33333%;` removes that extra pixel in your version. http://jsfiddle.net/sVu4R/6/

Comment: You have just made a wide padding, so that you don't easily see that there is an extra pixel unused. If you make the padding one pixel and black, you clearly see the extra pixel. Using `width: 33.33333%` works in Firefox, but not in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You need box-sizing property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: It's a pretty good site with useful information. Why do so many people hate it?

Comment: @Matijs Did a google search and you're right, people are saying its a bad site for resource. Though Ive seen good information there.

Comment: I'm a newbie relatively-speaking, but w3schools has helped me a lot... otherwise I'd be asking a lot more questions here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @user2824289 Start adding “MDN” to your searches to get even better results. Also http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Comment: For each of the three kings or the #threekings container?

Comment: Nevermind, no luck with either... But it looks like you wanted them to be for each of the three kings (divs), because putting that code in #threekings screwed up the alignment...

Answer (score 0):

Percentage widths in CSS are each calculated independently. As such, you're ending up with three 333px divs, and one pixel left over.

If the parent element has a fixed width, just set the three columns to the appropriate sizes (333px, 334px, 333px) to fill the container. No need for percentages!

Comment: but don't I have to stick with percentages for responsive compatibility (when I get there...one step at a town)?

Comment: At any rate, I went with your approach, made the middle div 33.4%.  Thanks!